# retrofit gives 500 internal server error when I add only one item, but postman response works fine

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to debug this issue about "Http 500 internal access error" .For that the code is as shown below:

```
private void submitOrder() {
    List<String> itemIds = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> itemQuantity = new ArrayList<>();

    for (FoodTruckItem foodTruckItem : foodTruckItemList) {
        itemIds.add(foodTruckItem.getItemId());
        itemQuantity.add(foodTruckItem.getItemQuantityOrdered());
    }


    if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(this)) {
        Observable<GenericResponse> results = RetroClient.getApiService()
                .submitOrder("******", "", total,
                        "anywhere", "", "*****", itemIds, itemQuantity,
                        foodtruckInfo.getFoodTruckId());
        results.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<GenericResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        unsubscribe();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MyCartActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(GenericResponse response) {
                        showOrderCompleteFragment();
                    }

                });
    } else {

    }
}
```

Here, what happens is when I send webservice with 2 items this works fine, but for one item it gives 500 internal server error. But for every case postman successfully creates order

The postman response is as shown below:

[image: web service response]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `Map` for `itemIds` and `itemQuantity` instead of `List<String>/List<Integer>` as below :

Define below parameter in `RetroClient.getApiService().submitOrder()`

```
@FieldMap Map<String, String> itemIdsMap
@FieldMap Map<String, String> itemQuantityMap
```

Now pass `itemIds` and `itemQuantity` value as below :

```
Map<String, String> itemIdsMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> itemQuantityMap = new HashMap<>();

String itemIds = "item_id[%d]";
String itemQuantity = "item_quantity[%d]";

for (int i = 0; i < foodTruckItemList.size(); i++) {
     itemIdsMap.put(String.format(itemIds, i), foodTruckItemList.get(i).getItemId());
     itemQuantityMap.put(String.format(itemQuantity, i), foodTruckItemList.get(i).getItemQuantityOrdered());                
}
```